# How to create hdfs replication using Cloudera CM API

Tags: hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-manager

Hi I am new to hadoop and wanted to create hdfs replication using cloudera manager API.

How to create hdfs replication using Cloudera CM API?

Answer (score 0):

After doing lots of research, I was able to create the below command which will replicate from one location to the other in hdfs within same cluster.

But, with slight variations we can do remote cluster replication also.

Comment: I am sorry here is the command curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -u admin:admin -d '{ "items": [ { "hdfsArguments" : { "sourceService" : { "clusterName" : "cluster", "serviceName" : "hdfs" }, "sourcePath" : "/tmp/hasan_rep_test", "destinationPath" : "/tmp/hasan_rep", "mapreduceServiceName" : "yarn", "dryRun" : false  } } ] }' "http://CM-SERVER:7180/api/v9/clusters/Cluster%201/services/hdfs/replications"